# Perl - undefined subroutine

Tags: perl, subroutine

I have the following Perl code:

```
use Email::Sender::Simple;
use IO::Socket::SSL;

IO::Socket::SSL::set_defaults(SSL_verify_mode => SSL_VERIFY_NONE);

Email::Sender::Simple::sendmail($email, { transport => $transport });
```

When I run it I get this error:

```
Undefined subroutine &Email::Sender::Simple::sendmail called at script.pl line 73.
```

If I change the code to have the following, then it works:

```
use Email::Sender::Simple qw(sendmail);

sendmail($email, { transport => $transport });
```

Can someone explain why I had to change the code for sendmail, while I did NOT have to change the code for set_defaults to look like:

```
use IO::Socket::SSL qw(set_defaults);

set_defaults(SSL_verify_mode => SSL_VERIFY_NONE);
```

Comment: Well I just tried changing my code to have `use IO::Socket::SSL qw(set_defaults);` and `set_defaults(SSL_verify_mode => SSL_VERIFY_NONE);` and I got an error saying `"set_defaults" is not exported by the IO::Socket::SSL module`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the code `Email/Sendmail/Simple.pm`. There is no `sendmail` subroutine in that program. Instead, if you look at the header, you'll see:

```
use Sub::Exporter -setup => {
  exports => {
    sendmail        => Sub::Exporter::Util::curry_class('send'),
    try_to_sendmail => Sub::Exporter::Util::curry_class('try_to_send'),
  },
};
```

I'm not familiar with [Sub::Exporter](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Sub-Exporter-0.986/lib/Sub/Exporter.pm), but I did notice this description.

> The biggest benefit of Sub::Exporter over existing exporters (including the ubiquitous Exporter.pm) is its ability to build new coderefs for export, rather than to simply export code identical to that found in the exporting package.

Oh...

So, the purpose of using `Sub::Exporter` is to *export* subroutine names that aren't subroutines in your package.

If you're interested, you can read the tutorial of [Sub::Exporter](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Sub-Exporter-0.986/lib/Sub/Exporter/Tutorial.pod), but it appears it has the ability to export subroutines under different names.

Thus, `Email::Sender::Simple::sendmail` isn't a subroutine, but that `sendmail` can still be exported.

Comment: Maybe too much detail, but I can see where `set_defaults` is exported by `IO::Socket::SSL`

Comment: If you wanted to avoid importing, you could use `Email::Sender::Simple->send(...)` instead of `Email::Sender::Simple::sendmail(...)`.